# Silence the header and access log output, but still show the error_log()/syslog() output from php built-in server

Tags: php, php-8

I start my server like this:

`php -c /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php.ini -S 127.0.0.1:8080 index.php`

NOTE: Yes, I know about the `-q` option, but that also silences the `errog_log()` and `syslog()` output. I want to see those, because I read them while developing and debugging. Please don't offer that as the solution **unless you also know of a way** to configure something else so that the `error_log()` and `syslog()` still get shown... or if there is just some completely different method of accessing that `error_log()` and `syslog()` output. :)

When I browse to the home page of my application, I'm swamped with useless output which completely hides my error logs that I add to help me debug. For example. I added `error_log(uniqid()." testing")` to my page and reloaded my browser and was attacked with this output:

```
$ php -c /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php.ini -S 127.0.0.1:8080 index.php 
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:39 2021] PHP 8.0.12 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8080) started
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65498 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65499 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 617b76249f935 testing   <--- NOTE: the only line I actually wanted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65498 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65499 [200]: GET /css/normalize.css?v=1635481124
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65501 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65501 [200]: GET /js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom-theme/jquery-ui.min.css?v=1635481124
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65503 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65499 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65506 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65507 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65501 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65509 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65511 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65503 [200]: GET /css/unpkg/base-min.css?v=1635481124
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65513 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65506 [200]: GET /css/unpkg/grids-min.css?v=1635481124
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65507 [200]: GET /css/grids-responsive-custom.css?v=1635481124
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65509 [200]: GET /css/site.css?v=1635481124
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65511 [200]: GET /js/common.js?v=1635481124
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65513 [200]: GET /js/ga.js?v=1635481124
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65503 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65506 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65507 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65509 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65511 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65513 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65515 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65515 [200]: GET /images/herdboss-logo.svg
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65517 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65515 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65517 [200]: GET /images/index/index-apps.png
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65519 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65519 [200]: GET /images/herdboss-icon-120.png
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65521 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65523 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65521 [200]: GET /images/app/app_store_badge_us-uk_135x40.svg
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65525 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65519 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65523 [200]: GET /images/app/available-on-google-play.png
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65527 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65525 [200]: GET /images/facebook-icon-white.png
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65529 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65517 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65527 [200]: GET /images/youtube-icon-white.png
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65521 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65523 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65529 [200]: GET /images/instagram-icon-white.png
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65531 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65525 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65531 [200]: GET /css/ie-is-terrible.css?v=1635481124
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65527 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65529 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65531 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65533 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65535 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65533 [200]: GET /images/checkmark-no-padding.svg
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65535 [200]: GET /images/sheep-in-field.jpg
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65533 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:65535 Closing
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:49153 Accepted
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:49153 [200]: GET /favicon.ico
[Thu Oct 28 21:18:44 2021] 127.0.0.1:49153 Closing
```

When I've tried the `-q` option, it silences EVERYTHING, which is bad. Here is what it looks like when I use the `-q`:

```
$ php -c /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php.ini -q -S 127.0.0.1:8080 index.php
[Thu Oct 28 21:31:08 2021] PHP 8.0.12 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8080) started
```

Notice that it doesn't show the `testing` error_log() that I included in the page. It silences -everything- and not just the http header messages.

How can I show the `error_log()` and `syslog()` messages and get rid of all the useless socket connection notices and access_log output?